# WPF adding subitem to ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with WPF and have ListViewItems like this:

```
<ListViewItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="docx.png" Height="30"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="image"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

What this XAML code does is adding a stack panel with an image inside into a ListViewItem. I'd like to know how to achieve this programmatically. For example, I initiated a ListViewItem instance and can access its content. But this class doesn't have any fields like subitems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define items in Xaml, ListView allows you to define structure and template of binded items. Use `ItemsSource` property or attach a list of items in codebehind `MyView.ItemsSource=MyList`
Remember that the object must have public `Docname` property (all the properties you want to bind need to be public)
Adding Items to MyItems will add it to listView (MyItems need to be ObservableCollection or you need to manually do `MyView.Items.Refresh()`

```
<ListView x:Name="MyView" ItemsSource ="{Binding MyItems}"  
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>//define items container, uniformGrid, stackpanel...
        <UniformGrid Columns="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> //define your item template
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image Source="{Binding Docname}" Height="30"></Image>
           <TextBlock Text="image"></TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

If you want different template for each item you can use 
[http://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-listview-itemtemplateselector
Or completly in xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyView" ItemsSource ="{Binding MyItems}"  
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>//define items container, uniformGrid, stackpanel...
        <UniformGrid Columns="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate> 
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}"> 
     <ContentControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Mytype}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Docname}" Height="30"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="image"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type My2type}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Docname}" Height="30"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="2  type image"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ContentControl.Resources>
     </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Great answer. I guess my idea of accessing UI components in my back-end logic is just against the idea of WPF. Using templates makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `ItemsSource` and `Binding` to easly access data, you provide in your list.
But, if you have `ListView` called `MyListView`, this is how you could access controls inside first item:

```
var item = MyListView.Items[0] as ListViewItem;
var firstItemChild = item?.Content as StackPanel;
var image = firstItemChild?.Children[0];
```